# Heroku command not found when deploy

Tags: python-3.x, heroku, heroku-postgres

I am trying to deploy Python code and connect to my database following this [tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-heroku-postgres-databases-from-outside-of-heroku) to get the database URL. In my `Procfile` I have:

```
web: DATABASE_URL=$(heroku config:get DATABASE_URL -a tmaminapi) python final.py
```

After deploying I see this in my logs:

```
2020-12-25T09:02:11.462258+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `DATABASE_URL=$(heroku config:get DATABASE_URL -a tmaminapi) python final.py`

2020-12-25T09:02:14.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded

2020-12-25T09:02:14.800250+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: heroku: command not found
```

That means I can't get the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable as I expected. Why can't Heroku can't find the `heroku` command-line tool in their own application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Procfile` should just contain

```
web: python final.py
```

Heroku config vars are available in the environment by default, so there is no need to set them yourself in your `Procfile`.

In general, there should never be a need to use the `heroku` CLI from your dynos and therefore it isn't installed there. The [documentation you referenced](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-heroku-postgres-databases-from-outside-of-heroku) is specifically for accessing Heroku Postgres databases from *outside* of Heroku.